# how to use bitbucket access token with JGit instead of user / pass

Tags: java, authentication, bitbucket, git-clone, jgit

I'm googling without any luck about how to use bitbucket access token instead of user / password with JGit client library.

The code below is about cloning a repo using a bitbucket user / pass.. How should I change this code to use bitbucket access token?

```
            Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI("https://bitbucket.myserver.net/scm/d1app/mobile-testing-scenarios.git")
                    .setDirectory(new File("/home/darena/repo_download_path"))
                    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("bitbucketUser", "bitbucketPass"))
                    .call();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver075/personal-access-tokens-1018784848.html?utm_campaign=in-app-help&utm_medium=in-app-help&locale=de_DE%2Cde&utm_source=stash#Personalaccesstokens-usingpersonalaccesstokens) says to use the token as a password.